# How to make CMake target executed whether specified file was changed?

Tags: cmake, antlr

I'm trying to use ANTLR in my C++ project. I made a target for running ANTLR generator for specified grammar and made main prjct dependent from it.

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(GenerateParser
    COMMAND ${ANTLR_COMMAND} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar.g 
                             -o ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar
)

ADD_LIBRARY(MainProject ${LIBRARY_TYPE} ${TARGET_SOURCES} ${TARGET_OPTIONS})
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(MainProject GenerateParser)
```

The problem is that ANTLR generator running every time I build project and consumes enough time. How can I make it run only whether my grammar has been changed? Or may be it is possible to make ANTLR somehow generate parser only for out of date grammar.

Comment: We have this problem - with an `add_custom_target` always rebuilding.  Unfortunately the target is defined in an external module outside of our control.  So solutions to use `add_custom_command` are not applicable in this case.  I am looking for a solution to control when the target is invoked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

add_custom_command ***will*** do the trick, if you construct the call to it correctly.

Something like this should work:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar
  COMMAND ${ANTLR_COMMAND} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar.g
    -o ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar.g
)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(GenerateParser ALL
   DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar
)

ADD_LIBRARY(MainProject ${LIBRARY_TYPE} ${TARGET_SOURCES} ${TARGET_OPTIONS})
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(MainProject GenerateParser)
```

Here, the custom target will "build" every time, but the only thing it will do is build the custom command on whose output it depends, but if and only if the output of the custom command is out of date with respect to its DEPENDS file(s).

Comment: I've found this didn't work for me. Building a target that depends on a custom target that depends on a custom command output invokes the custom command every time, which in my case causes downstream rebuilds every time. Saving time to run the command is not a big deal, but having a ripple effect of out-of-date outputs is pretty tedious. Am I missing something with your solution?

Comment: It should only invoke the custom command when its input (the DEPENDS of add_custom_command) is newer than its output. Are you sure the values you are passing to OUTPUT and DEPENDS clauses are correct? Double-check the values of those elements with "message" in your CMake files.

Answer (score 6):

Besides proposed solution with custom target, if your target depends on some generated sources the common workflow is the following:

Add target that generates your source file. I recommend to use full paths to avoid mistakes.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${GENERATED_SOURCE_FILE}
    COMMAND ${GENERATION COMMAND}
    DEPENDS ${DEPENDENCIES}
)
```

Set GENERATED properties of your generated source file. So cmake won't complain about missing source file.

```
set_source_files_properties(${GENERATED_SOURCE_FILE} PROPERTIES
    GENERATED TRUE
)
```

Add generated source to your target as usual.

```
add_executable(${YOUR_TARGET} SOURCES ${GENERATED_SOURCE_FILE})
```

So in the proposed example ${GENERATION COMMAND} will only be launched if some of ${DEPENDENCIES} files were changed.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_custom_command.html) there's no need to manually mark the files as `GENERATED`, they're marked as such by default.

Answer (score 4):

Would add_custom_command do the trick?  Here you can specify the DEPENDS [depends...] which would make the command only execute when the dependent file changes.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:add_custom_command

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT output1 [output2 ...]
                 COMMAND command1 [ARGS] [args1...]
                 [COMMAND command2 [ARGS] [args2...] ...]
                 [MAIN_DEPENDENCY depend]
                 [DEPENDS [depends...]]
                 [IMPLICIT_DEPENDS <lang1> depend1 ...]
                 [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
                 [COMMENT comment] [VERBATIM] [APPEND])
```

Comment: Seems not to work. As I understood DEPENDS only work with targets, e.g. whenever the dependent target was changed (libary rebuilt, etc.) command is executed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same question. After reading how the makefiles were generated (because cmake documentation leaves a lot to be desired), it looks like the best solution is to use add_custom_command of the OUTPUT form. Here's my example

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT
                   # In my cmake file I list every file generated
                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar/file1
                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar/file2
                   COMMAND ${ANTLR_COMMAND} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar.g
                   -o {PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar

                   # In my case I used a script checked into source control, 
                   # so I want to know when it changes too
                   DEPENDS ${ANTLR_COMMAND} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyGrammar.g)

# cmake caches are problematic, so list the files in a variable
set(generated_sources src/MyGrammar/file1 src/MyGrammar/file2)
add_library(yourlib ${list_of_source_files} ${generated_sources})
```

Then when you build cmake will check the command and grammar files for changes before deciding to re-generate sources.