# cmake does not copy file in custom command

Tags: cmake, copy, dependencies

I want to copy qml files from source directory to build directory. Following script works fine only first time. When I change any of the *.qml files and run make, they are not copied to build folder, they are not updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES *.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QMLS *.qml)

add_library(MyLib SHARED ${SOURCES} ${QMLS})

foreach(QmlFile ${QMLS})
  add_custom_command(TARGET MyLib POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${QmlFile} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyLib>)
endforeach()
```

Comment: Can you please add what CMake version and which build environment you are using/targeting? Generally speaking, adding non-source files to `add_library()` is for listing those files in generated IDE projects. It does not add a dependency to this file. I think what you are looking for is the target property [`LINK_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html): "Specifies a semicolon-separated list of full-paths to files on which the link rule for this target depends. The target binary will be linked if any of the named files is newer than it."

Comment: Suggested by @Florian setting `LINK_DEPENDS` property would fix the problem with minimum code's editing, but using *non-TARGET* `add_custom_command`, as answered by Angew, seems to be more appropriate here. If library linking doesn't *actually* depend from `.qml`, why should it be relinked every time these files are changed? If copied `.qml` files don't depends from library, why should content of original files be re-checked only if `.cpp` files are changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Angew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938697/3440745) is good, it is possible to eliminate usage of additional *target*. For doing this, `add_library` call should use *copied* `.qml` files  (instead of *original* ones, like in the script in the question post):

```
# This part is same as in Angew's answer
set(copiedQmls "")
foreach(QmlFile ${QMLS})
  get_filename_component(nam ${QmlFile} NAME)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${nam}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${QmlFile} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    DEPENDS ${QmlFile}
    COMMENT "Copying ${QmlFile}"
    VERBATIM
  )
  list(APPEND copiedQmls ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${nam})
endforeach()

# But instead of creating new target, we reuse library one.
add_library(MyLib SHARED ${SOURCES} ${copiedQmls})
```

When library *target* is built, it triggers *non-sources* files in `add_library` call to be updated (if there is corresponded `add_custom_command` call), but **updating non-source files doesn't force library *file* to be rebuilt**. This is why your original code doesn't work as expected.

Note, because `.qml` files are not recognized by CMake as sources, you **doesn't need** to set `GENERATED` property for them, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20902962/3440745).

Comment: Good point about using the library target to drive the copy commands; +1.

Answer (score 2):

Your are using the `TARGET` signature of `add_custom_command`, which means the commands are executed as part of building the `TARGET`. In your case, `POST_BUILD`, which means the commands will be run after the build of `MyLib` finishes. If `MyLib` is up to date and does not need to be re-built, the commands will not run.

You might want to use the output-generating signature (`OUTPUT`) instead. Something like this:

```
set(copiedQmls "")
foreach(QmlFile ${QMLS})
  get_filename_component(nam ${QmlFile} NAME)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${nam}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${QmlFile} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    DEPENDS ${QmlFile}
    COMMENT "Copying ${QmlFile}"
    VERBATIM
  )
  list(APPEND copiedQmls ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${nam})
endforeach()

add_custom_target(
  CopyQMLs ALL
  DEPENDS ${copiedQmls}
)
```

Note that unfortunately, the `OUTPUT` argument of `add_custom_command` does not support generator expressions, so `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR>` cannot be used there. I used `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` in the example above, you might need to customise this to suit your needs. [`${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR.html) can be used to specify the per-configuration directory for multiconfiguration generators.

Note the presence of the additional custom target in my code above. That's necessary, because CMake will only execute an output-producing custom command if something depends on that output. The custom command does that, by listing the outputs in its `DEPENDS` section.

Comment: You are using `add_custom_target` which is always being built. I want to copy `QML` files only if they were changed. Still I don't understand why my approach does not work. `MyLib` should be out of date if I change any of `QML` files because `QML` files are added to `MyLib` as dependencies `add_library(MyLib SHARED ${SOURCES} ${QMLS})`.

Comment: @beemaster Yes, the custom target itself is always considered out of date. But note that "building it" means 1) checking that its dependencies are up to date, and 2) executing its `COMMAND`. It doesn't have a `COMMAND`, so building it just means checking its dependencies - precisely what you want.

Comment: @beemaster I don't think that listing a file as a source of a (non-custom) target *automatically* makes the target re-build if that file changes. If that file is not part of the build (is not compiled or linked), it doesn't carry the dependency.

Comment: You are right. The solution you proposed works for me. Unfortunately `QML` files do not carry the dependency if added to `add_library`

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862300/how-to-make-cmake-target-executed-whether-specified-file-was-changed