# convert cmake snippet to function - not working

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with an executable and several plugins that each have QML and other files (e.g. images, svg).  Creating the CMake build for this involves installing the plugins and their associated files needed at runtime in the appropriate place.  The types of files and the relative locations make this a repetitive thing for each module, so I moved the repeated CMake code into one .cmake file that is included by each plugin's CMakeLists.txt.  It works great when it's just basic code in the .cmake file.  I recently thought I would convert that to a function, and haven't been able to get it to work.  I think I'm missing something fundamental about when a function gets called in the generation process.  After converting to a function, the copying of files does not work and ${copiedFiles} is empty after returning from the function call.

Here's the .cmake file, with the code that works commented out at the bottom.  The function implementation of that code is at the top.

```
# This convenience snippet expects ${RESOURCE_FOLDERS} and ${OUTPUT_DIR} to
# set.
#

function(copy_common_files RESOURCE_FOLDERS OUTPUT_DIR copiedFiles)
    foreach(folder ${RESOURCE_FOLDERS})
        file(GLOB QML_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.qml)
        file(GLOB SVG_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.svg)
        file(GLOB QMLDIR_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/qmldir)
        file(GLOB APPCFG_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/appconfig.json)
        file(GLOB TRANSLATION_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.ts)
        file(GLOB QRC_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.qrc)
        set(FILES_TO_COPY
            ${QML_FILES} ${SVG_FILES} ${QM_FILES} ${QMLDIR_FILE} ${QRC_FILES}
            ${APPCFG_FILE} ${TRANSLATION_FILES}
        )

        foreach(file ${FILES_TO_COPY})
            get_filename_component(nam ${file} NAME)
            add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${folder}/${nam}
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${file} ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${folder}
                DEPENDS ${file}
                COMMENT "Copying ${file}"
                VERBATIM
                )
            list(APPEND outputList ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${folder}/${nam})
            set(${copiedFiles} ${outputList} PARENT_SCOPE)
        endforeach()
    endforeach()

endfunction()

#foreach(folder ${RESOURCE_FOLDERS})
#    file(GLOB QML_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.qml)
#    file(GLOB SVG_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.svg)
#    file(GLOB QMLDIR_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/qmldir)
#    file(GLOB APPCFG_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/appconfig.json)
#    file(GLOB TRANSLATION_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.ts)
#    file(GLOB QRC_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${folder}/*.qrc)
#    set(FILES_TO_COPY
#        ${QML_FILES} ${SVG_FILES} ${QM_FILES} ${QMLDIR_FILE} ${QRC_FILES}
#        ${APPCFG_FILE} ${TRANSLATION_FILES}
#    )

#    foreach(file ${FILES_TO_COPY})
#        get_filename_component(nam ${file} NAME)
#        add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${folder}/${nam}
#            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${file} ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${folder}
#            DEPENDS ${file}
#            COMMENT "Copying ${file}"
#            VERBATIM
#            )
#        list(APPEND copiedFiles ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${folder}/${nam})
#    endforeach()
#endforeach()
```

An example of a plugin CMakeLists.txt that calls this is here, with the working way being just the include statement, not including the function call.

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC OFF)   # Set this to ON if you want resources compiled in

set(OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/AEPPApps/ImportFiles)

set(RESOURCE_FOLDERS
    .
    images
    )

include(copy_common_files)    # only this when not using 'function'
copy_common_files(${RESOURCE_FOLDERS} ${OUTPUT_DIR} copiedFiles)


# Adding ${copiedFiles} as a dependency below forces the conditional copy
# to get considered:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938239/cmake-does-not-copy-file-in-custom-command
add_library(ImportFiles SHARED ${copiedFiles})

target_compile_definitions(ImportFiles
    PRIVATE
    IMPORTFILESPLUGIN_LIBRARY
    NOMINMAX
    )

target_include_directories(ImportFiles
    PRIVATE
    .
    )

# Enable below when you want to compile resources for apps, then remove the copying above
#
#qt5_add_resources(ImportFiles_RESOURCES
#    ImportFiles.qrc
#    )

target_sources(ImportFiles
    PRIVATE
    Redacted.cpp

    )


target_link_libraries(ImportFiles
    PUBLIC
    REDACTED-lib

    PRIVATE
    Qt5::Core
    )

set_target_properties(ImportFiles PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
    ${OUTPUT_DIR}
    )
```

Comment: The function `copy_common_files` creates many `add_custom_command`'s, one for each generated source file, and sets output parameter `copiedFiles` to contain list of that source files. What exact **part of the function** is not worked? You may check value of output parameter with usual `message()` call.

Comment: Yes, good question.  Ultimately the files aren't being copied, and I now can see that ${copiedFiles} is empty after returning from the function call.

Comment: I just noticed that my input variable is a list which is getting truncated after the first value inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RESOURCE_FOLDERS` variable contains **two values**.

When pass them to the function, they are interpreted as the function's **two arguments** (`RESOURCE_FOLDERS` and `OUTPUT_DIR`).

**Way 1**. You may pass "multivalued" variable **quoted**:

```
copy_common_files("${RESOURCE_FOLDERS}" ${OUTPUT_DIR} copiedFiles)
```

Note, that quoting works only for *named* arguments.

Otherwise, that way is perfectly valid and used e.g. in implementation of [cmake_parse_arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html) command.

**Way 2**. Arrange the multivalued argument to the **end** in the function's **signature**, after the named arguments:

```
function(copy_common_files OUTPUT_DIR copiedFiles)
```

That function could be called as

```
copy_common_files(${OUTPUT_DIR} copiedFiles ${RESOURCE_FOLDERS})
```

Inside the function you may refer to the list of the rest arguments as `${ARGN}`:

```
foreach(folder ${ARGN})
```

This way is used in many non-internal CMake commands.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would a MACRO be a better choice in this situation?

Comment: No, the macro wouldn't resolve the problem with multivalued parameter. Also, macro has some specific about interpreting `ARGN`, so I found a function to be a better choice than a macro whenever both are applicable. But when a nested scope should be avoided by any cost, the macro is a good choice.