# How to rebuild a CMake target when the binary output of another changes?

Tags: cmake

### Background

I have a CMake project where I want to build some executables using a custom Clang plugin, which is also part of the same source tree. I want CMake to rebuild any targets that use this plugin when the plugin is rebuilt.

### Context

The plugin is a shared library and defined like so:

```
add_llvm_library(Plugin MODULE Plugin.cpp PLUGIN_TOOL opt)
```

If you aren't familiar with LLVM, `add_llvm_library` is effectively `add_library`. The plugin itself builds just fine.

I also have some executable targets, defined like so:

```
add_executable(TestProgram Test.cpp)
target_compile_options(TestProgram PUBLIC "-fplugin=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Plugin.so")
```

As you can see, they are configured to use the Clang plugin that is built as part of the same project.

### Problem

Two things need to be understood by CMake here:

1. The `Plugin` target is a dependency of `TestProgram`, as it cannot compile if `Plugin` has not been built, i.e. `Plugin.so` is not present.
2. `TestProgram` should be rebuilt whenever `Plugin.so` changes.

I started by doing `add_dependencies(TestProgram Plugin)`. This actually solves #1; the `TestProgram` target won't build until `Plugin` target has been built.

However, #2 is yet to be solved. Because `Plugin.so` is a compiler plugin used in building `TestProgram`, it is effectively an input. Even if the source files for `Plugin` do not change, a change in `Plugin.so` can very well affect the code generation and resulting binary for `TestProgram`.

How can I convince CMake that `Plugin.so` (i.e. the output of one target) is effectively an input to another target, and should cause that target to be rebuilt even if its source files have not changed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862300/how-to-make-cmake-target-executed-whether-specified-file-was-changed have you tried these solutions? (your question is not a duplicate because the 'compiler-plugin'-part makes it more difficult than the simple code-generation case) But maybe it could be helpful.

Comment: I am surprised add_dependency does not work, because the documentation seems to suggest it would serve your case perfectly. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html  are you sure the .so-compiler-plugin is a top-level-target?

Comment: The `add_dependencies(TestProgram Plugin)` call is useful as it forces TestProgram to be built only after the target `Plugin` is built. For make an executable target to be re-compiled on a file changed, add this file to `add_executable` call. E.g. `add_executable(TestProgram Test.cpp $<TARGET_FILE:Plugin>)`. Here `$<TARGET_FILE>` is a [generator-expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), which is expanded by CMake to the actual path of the file created by `Plugin` target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Attempting to add a non-source file to a target's sources list does not work and produces the following error during configuration (paraphrased): `Cannot find source file: Plugin.so; tried extensions .c, .cpp, ...`

Comment: @julaine `add_dependency` does work for ensuring `Plugin` always builds before test program, but it stops there. It doesn't create the "input file" relationship. Also, based on the language, it sounds like it's working as intended: `Makes a top-level <target> depend on other top-level targets to ensure that they build before <target> does.` I don't believe `add_dependency` is meant to create that relationship.

Comment: "produces the following error during configuration" - The error is emitted because in the directory where you call `add_executable` CMake doesn't know that the `Plugin.so` file is generated (probably, you call `add_llvm_library` in some other directory). But you may explicitly tell CMake that the file is generated: `set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Plugin.so PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)`. It should be called from the same `CMakeLists.txt` where you call `add_executable`. (Unfortunately, generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE:Plugin>`  doesn't work in `set_source_files_properties`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev doing `set_source_files_properties` does let configuration succeed (nice detective work there... I am calling it in a different directory), but nevertheless does not cause `TestProgram` to be rebuilt when `Plugin` is.